# xbox 360 install only reaching 2049mb before stopping

Tags: xbox-360

my sons xbox 360 is using a memory stick for storage. He put his xbox on today and it told me there was missing or corrupt files and to reinstall... I have tried to do this 3 times tonight already and its hitting my last nerve as its doing 2049mb out of the 7000 odd and then stopping any ideas on what this could be? im thinking it could be his disc drive as you hear the disc running upto the 2030 mark and then the disc stops. this is for gta v by the way lol

Comment: I could be an issue with the memory stick. You may want to consider trying a different USB stick and seeing if the issue still occurs.

Comment: How large is the drive? Cause it sounds like you have a 2 gb drive... 2048mb in a 2 gb drive... Or at least there is only 2 GB left

Comment: The Xbox 360 had at minimum a 4GB drive. A 2GB drive wouldn't make sense considering the FileSystem overhead, system overhead, and the fact that a 2GB HDD is actually 1.86GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can isolate this to 1 of 3 possible issues:

- The Disc itself
- The Xbox 360 or internal disc drive
- The HDD or USB that you're installing to

The steps I would take would be the following:

- **Ensure there is enough free space**. The Xbox 360 should automatically check, but it can't hurt to check.
- **Try an alternative HDD or USB**. If this works you may want to reformat the original or simply replace it if it continues to give you issues.
- **Try installing a different game**. If this fails, then it can indicate a possible problem with the Xbox 360 or the disc drive itself. If this happens, trying another Xbox 360 would be a good next step.
- **Check for scratches on the disc**. You may need to get the disc rebuffed if it appears to be severely scratched up, or if you see deep scratches.